# Error When Trying to Load a LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript, html

I have a LWC where I am trying to display a list of records of that same Object, I have been able to insert the record successfully but after that the list has not being displayed, and after some updates and research, now I get the Error during LWC component phase (see picture please), an I have been updating my LWC but nothing changes.

[image]

And here it is my HTML:

```
    <!-- sldsValidatorIgnore -->
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Dog Grooming">
         <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Dog_Grooming__c" value={dogGrooming} onsuccess={handleSuccess}>   
            <lightning-input-field field-name="Name" value={name}></lightning-input-field>
            <lightning-input-field field-name="Pet_Name__c" value={pName} required="true"></lightning-input-field>
            <lightning-input-field field-name="Pet_Owner__c" value={pOwner} required="yes"></lightning-input-field>
            <lightning-input-field field-name="Pet_Address__c" value={pAddress}></lightning-input-field>
            <lightning-input-field field-name="Pet_Security_Number__c" value={pSSN} required="yes"></lightning-input-field>
            <lightning-input-field field-name="Pet_Phone_Number__c" value={pPhone}></lightning-input-field>

            <lightning-button
            class="slds-var-m-top_small"
            type="submit"
            name="submit"
            label="Save"
            onclick={createRecord}
            ></lightning-button>
        </lightning-record-edit-form>
        <template if:true={petRecords}>
            <lightning-card title="Awesome Pets!">
                <ul>
                    <template for:each={wiredPets.data} for:item="record">
                        <li key={record.Id}>
                            <p>Groomer Name: {record.Name}</p>
                            <p>Pet Name: {record.Pet_Name__c}</p>
                            <p>Pet Owner: {record.Pet_Owner__c}</p>
                            <p>Pet Address: {record.Pet_Address__c}</p>
                            <p>Pet SSN: {record.Pet_Security_Number__c}</p>
                            <p>Pet Phone: {record.Pet_Phone_Number__c}</p>
                        </li>
                    </template>
                </ul>
                <template if:true={wiredPets}>
                    <div style="height: 500px;">
                        <template if:true={wiredPets.data}>
                            <lightning-datatable
                            key-field="id"
                            data={data}
                            columns={columns}>
                        </lightning-datatable>
                        </template>
                        <template if:true={wiredPets.error}>
                            <p>Error getting records: {wiredPets.error}</p>
                        </template>
                    </div>
                </template>
            </lightning-card>
        </template>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

Here it is my JS:

```
import { LightningElement, track, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { createRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
import getPetList from '@salesforce/apex/PetRecordsController.getPetList';


export default class Dog_Grooming extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    @wire(getPetList) wiredPets;
    @api recordId;
    @track petRecords = [];
    @track name;
    @track pName;
    @track pSSN;
    @track pOwner;
    @track pPhone;
    @track pAddress;
    @track data = [];

    @track columns = [
        { label: 'Groomer Name', fieldName: 'Name' },
        { label: 'Pet Name', fieldName: 'Pet_Name__c' },
        { label: 'Pet Address', fieldName: 'Pet_Address__c' },
        { label: 'Pet Security Number', fieldName: 'Pet_Security_Number__c' },
        { label: 'Pet Phone Number', fieldName: 'Pet_Phone__c' },
        { label: 'Pet Owner', fieldName: 'Pet_Owner__c' }
    ];
    @track petsList;

    @wire (getPetList) wiredPets({data, error}) {
        if(data) {
            this.petsList = data;
            console.log(data);
        }else if(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    createRecord() {
        const fields = {
            Name: this.name,
            Pet_Name__c: this.pName,
            Pet_Owner__c: this.pOwner,
            Pet_Address__c: this.pAddress,
            Pet_Security_Number__c: this.pSSN,
            Pet_Phone__c: this.pPhone
        };

        const recordInput = { apiName: 'Dog_Grooming__c', fields };
            createRecord(recordInput)
            .then(_response => {
                this.showToast('Success', 'Record Saved!', 'success');
                this.showPetRecords();
            })
        .catch(error => {
            this.handleError(error);
        });
}

    navigateToRecordPage() {
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__recordPage',
            attributes: {
                recordId: this.recordId,
                objectApiName: 'Dog_Grooming__c',
                actionName: 'view'
            }
        });
    }

    showPetRecords() {
        if(this.wiredPets && this.wiredPets.data) {
            this.petsList = this.wiredPets.data;
            console.log(this.petsList);
        } else {
            console.log('No data');
        }
    }
   

    showToast() {
        const event = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: 'Record Saved',
            message: 'Pet Registered',
            variant: 'variant',
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(event);
    }

    handleError(error) {
        let message = '';
        if(error === undefined) return 'apex error';
        if(error.message !== undefined && typeof error.message === 'string'){
            message = error.message + '\n';
        }
        if (error.body !== undefined && Array.isArray(error.body)) {
            message += error.body.message;
            if(error.body.output !== undefined && Array.isArray(error.body.output.errors)) {
                let msg = error.body.output.errors.map((e) => e.message).join(', ');
                errorMessage += '\n' + msg;
            }
        }
        this.showToast('Error', message, 'error');
    }
}
```

And finally my Apex Class

```
public without sharing class PetRecordsController {
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static List<SObject> getPetList() {
    //try{
    return
        [SELECT
            Id,
            Name,
            Pet_Address__c,
            Pet_Name__c,
            Pet_Owner__c,
            Pet_Phone_Number__c,
            Pet_Security_Number__c
        FROM Dog_Grooming__c
        WHERE Pet_Name__c LIKE '%'];
    //}
    /*catch(Exception e){
        throw new AuraHandledException('An error ocurred: ' + e.getMessage());
    }*/
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a getter around it so you return an empty list if `data` is undefined.

```
get pets() {
    return !wiredPets?.data ? [] : wiredPets.data;
}
```

Then bind to this getter in your markup instead.

```
<template for:each={pets} for:item="pet">
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I already made those changes but I got the same error. The LWC is not even loading 

Answer (score 0):

Your code has several problems.

First, you can't have redundant properties:

```
    @wire(getPetList) wiredPets;
...
    @wire (getPetList) wiredPets({data, error}) {
        if(data) {
            this.petsList = data;
            console.log(data);
        }else if(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
```

The latter property overwrites the former.

As a consequence, the following method is trying to access properties of a function, not a property:

```
    showPetRecords() {
        if(this.wiredPets && this.wiredPets.data) {
            this.petsList = this.wiredPets.data;
            console.log(this.petsList);
        } else {
            console.log('No data');
        }
    }
```

Same thing for the various parts in your template.

Second, the `showPetRecords` method isn't how you refresh data. You want to use `refreshApex` instead.

```
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';

...

refreshApex(this.wiredPets);
```

You'll do this after changing your data.

```
createRecord() {
   const fields = { ... };
   const recordInput = { apiName: 'Dog_Grooming__c', fields };
   createRecord(recordInput).then(
    () => {
      this.showToast(...);
      refreshApex(this.wiredPets);
   }
}
```

`petRecords` is never actually used for anything, so part of your template doesn't make sense, either.

```
    <template if:true={petRecords}>
```

is always true, and so is:

```
    <template if:true={wiredPets}>
```

Further, `@track` isn't necessary for simple objects, so most of that logic is also redundant.

Putting it all together, your JS should look more like this:

```
import { LightningElement, track, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { createRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
import getPetList from '@salesforce/apex/PetRecordsController.getPetList';
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';

export default class Dog_Grooming extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    @wire(getPetList) wiredPets;
    @api recordId;
    name;
    pName;
    pSSN;
    pOwner;
    pPhone;
    pAddress;

    @track columns = [
        { label: 'Groomer Name', fieldName: 'Name' },
        { label: 'Pet Name', fieldName: 'Pet_Name__c' },
        { label: 'Pet Address', fieldName: 'Pet_Address__c' },
        { label: 'Pet Security Number', fieldName: 'Pet_Security_Number__c' },
        { label: 'Pet Phone Number', fieldName: 'Pet_Phone__c' },
        { label: 'Pet Owner', fieldName: 'Pet_Owner__c' }
    ];

    createRecord() {
        const fields = {
            Name: this.name,
            Pet_Name__c: this.pName,
            Pet_Owner__c: this.pOwner,
            Pet_Address__c: this.pAddress,
            Pet_Security_Number__c: this.pSSN,
            Pet_Phone__c: this.pPhone
        };

        const recordInput = { apiName: 'Dog_Grooming__c', fields };
            createRecord(recordInput)
            .then(_response => {
                this.showToast('Success', 'Record Saved!', 'success');
                return refreshApex(this.wiredPets);
            })
        .catch(error => {
            this.handleError(error);
        });
    }

    navigateToRecordPage() {
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__recordPage',
            attributes: {
                recordId: this.recordId,
                objectApiName: 'Dog_Grooming__c',
                actionName: 'view'
            }
        });
    }

    showToast() {
        const event = new ShowToastEvent({
            title: 'Record Saved',
            message: 'Pet Registered',
            variant: 'variant',
        });
        this.dispatchEvent(event);
    }

}
```

You'll need to update your template as well.